# InfoWindow in google maps does not always display full text

Tags: javascript, google-maps

the infowindow in google map is not showing some text,
in the below code, the last part of contentstring, ie, amount1 is shown sometimes ...not always!

the same string is logged to console and I am able to see the amount there , but it is not
appearing in infowindow sometimes. any help on this will be appreciated.

```
var contentString = street1+' '+city1+' '+state1+' '+zipcode1+' '+'Amount '+amount1;
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
console.log(contentString);
```

Comment: please explain more detail.what kind of condition cannot display amount?And could you show me infowindow`s css code?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the maxWidth of the InfoWindow:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
  maxWidth: 500
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved by adding a div for the content of the infoWindow:

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<div style="line-   height:1.35;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">ADD CONTENT</div>'});
```